# Laravel 8 error 404 page not found , I wonder where did I do wrong here?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-8

At the most basic of understanding, I've been trying to match the route and the *form* action. I think that I am doing it right but I wonder why does the error keeps on showing ? I may have missed something anywhere but I just really couldn't find it. Please help. In a very tight schedule, I need to complete this project by tuesday

P.S : when i submit the form it goes to this address http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/edit/1 .

Form

```
<x-layout>
    <x-setting heading="Edit Staff Profile">
        <div class="flex flex-col">
            <form method="POST" action="/profile/edit/{{$profil->id}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf

                <div class="mb-6">
                    <label class="block mb-2 uppercase font-bold text-sm text-gray-700" for="images">
                        Profile photo
                    </label>
                    <input type="file" name="images">
                </div>
```

Route

```
Route::get('profile', [UserController::class, 'index'])->middleware('auth')->name('profile');
Route::get('profile/edit/{id}', [UserController::class, 'show'])->middleware('auth');
Route::post('profile/edit/{id}', [UserController::class, 'update'])->middleware('auth');
```

UserController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Profile;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $id =  Auth::user()->id;
        $info = User::where('id', $id)->first();

        return view('profile', compact('info'));
    }

    // public function create()
    // {
    //     return view('staffrecord.create');
    // }

    public function store()
    {
        $attributes = request()->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'username' => 'required|min:3|max:255|unique:users,username',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'required|min:7|max:255',
        ]);

        if (auth()->attempt($attributes)) {
            return redirect('/')->with('success', 'Your account has been created.');
        }

        return redirect('/profile')->with('errors', 'Authentication failed.');
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $profil = User::findOrFail($id);

        return view('staffrecord.edit', compact('profil'));
    }

    public function edit()
    {
        $id = Auth::user()->id;
        $profil = Profile::findOrFail($id);
        return view('staffrecord.edit', compact('profil'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $data = Profile::findOrFail($id);
        $data->staff_id = $request->staff_id;
        $data->name = $request->name;
        $data->gender = $request->gender;
        $data->address = $request->address;
        $data->email = $request->email;
        $data->phonenumber = $request->phonenumber;
        $data->department = $request->department;

        $data->save();

        return redirect('/')->route('profile');
    }
}
```

Comment: try ``php artisan optimize:clear`` if you recently edited routes. also if it doesn't fix share your full error that you're getting.

Comment: just tried it. it doesnt work. i updated the url it goes to when i click on the submit button on my post

Comment: I always name my routes: Route::post('profile/edit/{id}', [UserController::class, 'update'])->name('user.update')-> middleware('auth').... Then form action looks like this: 
            <form method="POST" action="{{route('user.update', ['id' =>$profil->id]) }}"

Comment: 1) Run `php artisan route:list` and confirm that your route(s) are all listed correctly. 2) You're using `Profile::findOrFail($id);` which will result in a `404` if Laravel is unable to find a record with the given `$id`.

Comment: as @Peppermintology said a user may has his logins but they may not have setup their profiles so when you do such request profile find will fail and return to 404 error. Use ``updateOrCreate()`` if that's functionality you're looking for.

Comment: also to make a note use foreign keys in Profile table linking to user id it's not necessary that a user->id say 1 will have profile->id 1

Comment: @Peppermintology I just realized I was using the wrong Model. I change the Profile::findOrFail($id) to User::findOrFail($id) and now it works ! and as Sumit kumar pointed out, they havent set up their profiles thats why. thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user may has his logins but they may not have setup their profiles so when you do such request profile find will fail and return to 404 error.

Also to make a note `ALWAYS` use foreign keys in Profile table linking to user id it's not necessary that a user->id say 1 will have profile->id 1.

in User model add this function:

```
public function profile() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Profile');
}
```

Then load user profile in update function of controller like:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
    $user = User::with('profile')->findOrFail($id);
    if (is_null($user->profile){ echo 'user don't has profile'; }
    //Update profile from within 

    $user->profile()->updateOrCreate([$request->all()]);

    //NOTE request->all is not safe
}
```

use `updateOrCreate()` for in case user does not have a profile.

Answer (score 1):

I always name my routes:

```
Route::post('profile/edit/{id}', [UserController::class, 'update'])->name('user.update')-> middleware('auth')
```

Then form action looks like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('user.update', ['id' =>$profil->id]) }}"
```

This way 'id' defined in route will be easier to be identified.
Naming routes and using route() may save you some headaches when moving to production.